# Bulk row values rename in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big data set with tons of rows. I have one column in that data set with long row values. I want to rename these row values with shorter names and use the previous column values as a part of name. How can I do this without dictionary and list in Pandas. Because I cannot put every single value in a dict.

I have a dataset like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ywb4.png)
And I want something like this output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xGNT.png)

Answer (score 1):

I create a DF with random long strings inside.  I see you actually don't use them in the result.

[image]

```
df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()+1
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'] + '-U' + df['Col2'].astype('str')
df
```

[image]

Comment: I have one problem with this code. I have 700 unique values in col2 but after applying this code I have 50000 unique rows (the entire data set row number)

Comment: I don't think it's the code.  You got a URL link to your data ?

Comment: It is the exact your code. I have not uploaded my code so I do not have any link. You know what is the problem. Imagine there are multiple row values with the same values in col 2. In this case your code does not work very well. Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I've tried, I cannot reproduce the problem.  I've tried extra columns, row, etc...

Comment: @EBDC I have updated the images in the post. Please try your code with this samples then you can see the problem.

Comment: The codes does not look at Col2.  It ignore Col2.  So your 50000 problem is not related to the contents in Col2.  I see that you have a new requirement, ie the code now needs to look at Col2 and see what's repeated and assign the same number if it's repeated.  This is different from the original question when you show random string.

Comment: I have asked my question as a new post and tagged you under the post my friend.